# Can functions share background state variables in Julia?

Tags: methods, types, julia

In object-oriented languages, if I had a bunch of functions that all required the same set of parameters, I would create a helper class and have the functions be methods for that class.

In julia, I have an `NCDataset` and a set of functions that do something with the value in the dataset at a given variable, X, Y, Z, and T.

```
struct Helper
    var::String
    x::Int64
    y::Int64
    z::Int64
    t::Int64
end

function do_thing_1(helper::Helper, ds::NCDataset)
    return ds[helper.var][[helper.x,helper.y,helper.z,helper.t]*2
end

function do_thing_2(helper::Helper, ds::NCDataset)
    return ds[helper.var][[helper.x,helper.y,helper.z,helper.t]/2.0
end
```

However this is kind of verbose. Is there a way to do this so that the functions share state variables that are initialized somehwere? Or is that not a paradigm in multiple-dispatch languages?

Comment: Is this more verbose? In an OOP language, you would do `helper.do_thing_1(ds)`, while in julia, it's `do_thing_1(helper, ds)`? Do you mean the verbosity of wring the function?

Comment: yes, i mean in writing the functions. I guess in python i would do `self.variable`....

Comment: yeah. I think the simplest way of reducing verbosity is choosing a shorter name than `helper` :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Structures allow property destructuring, so you can turn them into local variables in the function:

```
function do_thing_1(helper::Helper, ds::NCDataset)
  (; var, x, y, z, t) = helper
  return ds[var][x, y, z, t]*2
end
```

For very short functions like this, this at least makes things less cluttered and easier to read. For longer functions, this can be a lot less verbose.

---

You can also destructure directly on the argument line:

```
function do_thing_1((; var, x, y, z, t), ds::NCDataset)
  return ds[var][x, y, z, t]*2
end

do_thing_1(helper, ds)
```

---

If you have the `helper` be a `NamedTuple` or a `Dictionary`, you can also do:

```
function do_thing_1(ds::NCDataset; var, x, y, z, t)
  return ds[var][x, y, z, t]*2
end

do_thing_1(ds; helper...)
```

Comment: thank you! What does the semicolon indicate here?

Comment: It's the syntax chosen for name-based unpacking. Positional unpacking has existed in Julia for a long time, eg. `(a, b, c) = [1, 5, 9]` will assign the corresponding elements by position. So when name-based unpacking was introduced, it was chosen that a semi-colon at the front would indicate that, because of the similarity with the syntax that indicates keyword arguments in functions.